# Sum of number in a binary tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I have a list that can contain either two natural numbers or two more lists.  Each of these lists also contains either two integers or two further lists, and so on.
e.i.: [[4, 7], [[3, 5], [9, 1]]]
I need to use recursion to calculate the sum of all the numbers in the tree and write the following code:

```
def getSum(tree):
    sum = 0
    for elemente in tree:
        if type(elemente)==int:
            sum += elemente
        else:
            sum = getSum(elemente)
    return sum
```

The code doesn't work because it returns sum always to 12, so my question is, how can I make it work but still using recursion?. Have I not recognize the base case correctly?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `sum = getSum(elemente)` before `return`?

Comment: You're right. Tried it but it sums just the first element so still doesn't work. I will edit it just in case

Comment: If you need that to be a recursion, you must keep `sum` outside the recursion loop. Otherwise, it will always reset to `0`.

Comment: It resets with each element so it just returns the sum of the last list. How can I make it so that it keeps track of sum?

Comment: correction: "..Otherwise, it will always reset to the last calculated `sum`".

Comment: if a take sum out of the funktions it throws an UnboundLocalError

Comment: Yep, it's a bit tricky. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

```
def getSum(tree):
    sum = 0
    for elemente in tree:
        if type(elemente)==int:
            sum += elemente
        else:
            sum += getSum(elemente)
    return sum

tree = [[4, 7], [[3, 5], [9, 1]]]
print(getSum(tree))
```

```
29
```

Alternatively, you can keep track of the `sum` outside the recursion loop.

For example like this:

```
def getSum(tree, sum = None):
    sum = sum or 0
    for elemente in tree:
        if type(elemente)==int:
            sum += elemente
        else:
            sum = getSum(elemente, sum)
    return sum

tree = [[4, 7], [[3, 5], [9, 1]]]
print(getSum(tree))
```

```
29
```

Comment: That works. Thank you. Is there a way to do it without adding an argument to the function?

Comment: yes, you are right, sorry. did not have my coffee yet. see the updated answer.